# how to login to user account from shell script with password in the script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, putty

I am writing a shell script to login to any user account with the password mentioned in the shell script itself. My shell Script is as follows:

```
mypass="helloworld"
echo mypass>su myaccount
```

After executing this shell script i am still in my current user account rather than in `myaccount`

TL;DR I want to know how to login to a user account via a shell script by just running it.

Comment: You need to use expect to send the password

Comment: If you execute your script with `./scrip.sh` then it will be executed in a new subshell. Even it the `su` worked as soon as that shell finisches you are left in your original account shell.

Answer (score 3):

Sending password through script is possible by using expect script, Below is the very basic expect script for login to su account and executing pwd command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn su myaccount          # Spawning the su process
expect "Password:*"         # Wait/expect for the Password string from the spawned process
send "uraccpassword\r"      # send the password to spawned process as an input.
expect "*bash*"
send "pwd\r"
expect "*bash*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login to an account without providing a password then you'll need to generate ssh keys from your account using `ssh-keygen` and copy the public key into the account you want to login to. Additionally, I would always set a passphrase on the generated keys and use `ssh-agent` to manage it.